# Select from table A which does not exist in table B

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to compose a SELECT statement for MySQL which select from table A what does not exist in table B.  For example:

Table A:

```
+------+
| BAND |
+------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
| 4    |
| 5    |
+------+
```

Table B:

```
+------+
| HATE |
+------+
| 1    |
| 5    |
+------+
```

So if table A is all bands, and table B is the bands I hate, then I only want bands I do NOT hate.  So the result of a select should be:

```
+------+
| BAND |
+------+
| 2    |
| 3    |
| 4    |
+------+
```

How would I write a single select for this? Here was my last attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.BAND = B.HATE WHERE B.HATE IS NULL;
```

EDIT: The line above has been fixed!  See comments below..."= NULL" versus "IS NULL".

Comment: @Michelle your query seems to be ok. why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: See my comment below.  For anyone else with the same problem "IS NULL" is not the same as "= NULL" in MySQL.  I tried one way and the query works, the other way it returns an empty set.  Strange!!!

Comment: Not only in MySQL, but on any SQL dialect. The `NULL` value in SQL has the property of being different to any other value, including another `NULL`. Because of that, you can't expect `= NULL` to work on a SQL query... you need to use `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would use a join

```
select A.*
from A left join B on A.BAND = B.HATE
where B.HATE IS NULL;
```

Remember: Create the appropriate indexes for your table

Comment: That's almost identical to what I tried (see response above).  You ask for only A.* in return from select statement...perhaps that's the issue.

Comment: and it should give you the right answer! (by the way, I posted this before your edit). This should return what you need. Or why do you say it is not returning what you need?

Comment: OK - I found the problem!  I was testing for "B.HATE = NULL", not "B.HATE IS NULL".  My text above was what I used to create my SQL command, but when I actually typed the code (into a PHP string) I changed it to = NULL.  Strange that they are different!?

Comment: @Michelle As far as I know, in SQL `NULL` is different to any other value, including other `NULL`. It is usual to find things like `a == Null` in programming languages, but (at least) in MySQL, if you want to filter null values, you need to use `IS NULL` to test a null value, or the `ISNULL()` function, which returns `TRUE` if the argument is null

Answer (score 8):

You can use `IN`, but it's super inefficient:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tableB)
```

Comment: Why is this better than using a join?

Comment: I would think this is slow if tables A or B are big (for small tables, the performance difference is practically nothing)

Comment: I never said it was better, I actually say the opposite. `IN` sucks, because it runs the inner query for every row checked (so, for each row in `tableA`).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tableB)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tableB GROUP BY id)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT BAND FROM A WHERE BAND NOT EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT HATE FROM B)
```

OR

```
SELECT BAND FROM A WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT HATE FROM B WHERE A.BAND = B.HATE);
```