# Eloquent/Query builder Laravel: Select from table A without exists in table B

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 table as below:

```
User: id, name

Room: id, room_name

User_Room: user_id, room_id
```

How can I select all user from table User, without user exist in Table Room_User ?

I already followed with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890367/select-from-table-a-which-does-not-exist-in-table-b) but I don't know how to convert query below to Eloquent or Query Building

```
select A.*
from A left join B on A.BAND = B.HATE
where B.HATE IS NULL;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Many to Many relationship between the tow Models then you can simply use [doesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method (Querying Relationship Absence section) :

```
$users = User::doesntHave('rooms')->get();
```

Comment: I have Many to Many relationship. It's like User: return $this->belongsToMany(Room::class, 'room_users')->withTimestamps();, and Room:  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'room_users')->withTimestamps(); But I got an error: Call to undefined method App\User::whereDoesntHave(). Can you explain that to me ? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry test it now with `doesntHave` !!

Comment: It's work like a charm. THank you so much bro. You save my day.

Comment: Happy to help ;)